# Wordpress get user by

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hi I am trying to have live search which searches for existing emails when a user registers. Below is my jquery script

```
$("#wjp_register input#user_email").change(function(){
    console.log("lol");
    var email=$("#wjp_register input#user_email").val();
      $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            dataType : 'JSON',
            url:"/wordpress/wp-content/themes/tsf/wpjobboard/job-board/check.php",
            data:"email-address="+email,
                success:function(result){
                if(result==0){
                    console.log(result);
                    $(".error").html(" Username available");
                }
                else{
                    console.log(result);
                    $(".error").html("Username already taken");
                    proceed = false;
                }
            }
         });

});
```

When i check the response in the developer console, the email is echoed successfully but the wordpress get_user_by doesnt seem to work.

My php script

```
<?php
$mm = $_POST['email-address'];

if ( isset( $_POST['email-address'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['email-address'] ) ) {

  //sanitize the data
  $email_addr = trim( strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['email-address'] ) ) );
  echo $email_addr;//This is printed successfullt
  echo "<br>";

  //This below part doesnt work :(
    if( false == get_user_by( 'email', $email_addr ) ) {
        echo "Doesnt exist";
    } else {
        echo "exists";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: `get_user_by` doesn't return boolean... it returns an object of a user. The docs show an example: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by

Comment: @BigChris "object or _false if no user is found_"

Comment: Whoops. My bad. Sorry! Would help if I read the docs to what is returned... perhaps you need to check is false with `===` rather than `==` ?

Comment: @ash Since you are echoing "Doesnt exist" or "exists", those are the possible values for `result` in your success callback. `result==0` will never be true because you're not sending `0` back anywhere. Also, what exactly do you mean when you say that it "doesn't work"? What specifically isn't working? What are you expecting vs what is actually happening? It is a bit unclear if an unexpected value is being returned by `get_user_by` or if an unexpected value is being sent to the javascript callback.

Comment: @ash what is the output of var_dump(get_user_by('email', $email_addr)); ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have included wp in your check.php file? Otherwise the function get_user_by doesn't exist.

Comment: @SimonSchärer Thanks dude, including the wp_load.php file worked now, should have thought of that

Comment: @PatrickQ Oh yh that too, forgot to change that, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the correct way to use WP from an external file:

Include wp-blog-header.php if you need all of WP and want to fire all of the default hooks and actions.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

Includ wp-load.php if you only need the WP functions. It doesn't call wp() or invoke the template loader. So it's more lightweight!

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-load.php');
```

Comment: Whats difference does it make if use wp-blog-header.php or wp-load.php?

Comment: I modified my comment. In your case it's enough to include wp.load.php